# Automatically Copy and Insert a Row under the last filled cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I've been struggling with this problem for a while now, and I will try to explain it as best as I can.

I have an active table that is constantly increasing in row numbers. Each row has some properties and hidden cell that must be there. So my problem is this:

When I come to a row number ex.100 and the table is full I would like to enter a new row under that one with the same properties as the previous one.

I've managed to find few codes on internet and merge them into one functioning code but there are many problems with it. Here is the code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Sub BlankLine()

    Dim Col As Variant
    Dim BlankRows As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim R As Long
    Dim StartRow As Long

        Col = "C"
        StartRow = 123
        BlankRows = 1

            LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row

            Application.ScreenUpdating = False

            With ActiveSheet
For R = LastRow To StartRow + 1 Step -1
If IsEmpty(.Cells(R, Col)) = False Then
.Cells(R + 1, Col).EntireRow.Copy
.Cells(R + 1, Col).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
Range("A1").ClearOutline
End If
Next R
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

[image: You can see the part of the table here]

So here is what happens:
When you open the Excel it immediately searchers for rows after row number 123 with anything in cell C and copies the following empty row after the current one. The problem here is that every time I open the excel it does this and makes copies of copies of copies.

How I need it to happen:
When you open the Excel the code to be active and when you fill row number 124 to copy row 125 and insert it under row 124 and finish with row 124. Now to move the code to row number 125 and when this row has data in cell C to copy row 126 and move it under 125 and than stop and so on...

The idea is for the table to be actively increasing in rows and copying the data so you don't have to do it manually when it is filled.

Sorry about the long explanation, I hope there is a solution.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The code as you pasted it in the question shouldn't run: there is a Sub inside another Sub, and the first Sub doesn't have an `End Sub`. Also your indentation makes it quite hard the read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the code from the `Workbook_Open()` event in **`Worksheet_Change()`** event

Also make sure you use `Option Explicit` in all modules

Place this in the Sheet VBA module. It will trigger only when cells in column  C are updated

---

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.CountLarge = 1 Then   'Check that only 1 cell is being edited
        If Len(Target) > 0 Then     'Make sure the cell is not empty
            With Target
                If .Row > 1 And .Column = 3 Then    'Exclude Header row, and act on col 3
                    OptimizeApp True
                    MovePropRow Target
                    OptimizeApp False
                End If
            End With
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub MovePropRow(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim ws As Worksheet:    Set ws = Target.Parent
    Dim lr As Long:         lr = Target.Row
    Dim lrProp As Long:     lrProp = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

    If lrProp = lr Then
        ws.Range(ws.Cells(lr, "D"), ws.Cells(lr, "I")).Copy
        ws.Cells(lr + 1, "D").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
        ws.Range(ws.Cells(lr, "D"), ws.Cells(lr, "I")).Clear
        Target.Select
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub OptimizeApp(ByVal speedUp As Boolean)
    Application.Calculation = IIf(speedUp, xlCalculationManual, xlCalculationAutomatic)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = Not speedUp
    Application.DisplayAlerts = Not speedUp
    Application.EnableEvents = Not speedUp
End Sub
```

---

Test `Sheet3` - **`Before`**

[image: TestSheet3Before]

Test `Sheet3` - **`After`** `(typing "x" in Cell "C10")`

[image: TestSheet3After]